# Remove particular XML nodes using shell script

Tags: xml, bash

I have a sample xml file like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <weekly-schedule>
        <week>
            <game date="2015-09-10 17:30 PDT" start="Friday">
                <outcome outcome="pregame"/>
                <id>SP003188020000</id>
            </game>
            <game date="2015-09-13 10:00 PDT" start="Sunday">
                <outcome outcome="pregame"/>
                <id>SP003188030000</id>
            </game>
            <game date="2015-09-13 10:00 PDT" start="Monday">
                <outcome outcome="pregame"/>
                <id>SP003188030000</id>
            </game>
       </week>
  </weekly-schedule>
</root>
```

I wanted to remove all the games nodes in this xml which are start="Monday" and start="Friday"
Then I want to update xml file without above games. How can I achieve this?

Below is my script(can be bash) and I want to do this without using `xmlstarlet`.

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR=/users/Desktop/data
FILE=games.xml
cd $DIR

# tried to use xmllint 
DAY=$(echo "cat //root/weekly-schedule/week/game/@start" | xmllint --shell $FILE )
echo DAY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this one-liner awk command:

```
awk '/<game.*start="(Friday|Monday)">/{skip=1;} 1{if(!skip)print;} /<\/game>/{skip=0}' myfile.xml > newfile.xml && mv newfile.xml myfile.xml
```

The way it works is as follows:

- the first pattern matches the beginning of the lines we're willing to remove, and sets a variable `skip`
- the last pattern matches the end of the lines we're willing to remove, and unsets the variable `skip`
- we use the `skip` flag to conditionally output the lines, *before* we might reset `skip`

Comment: This `awk` command didnt work for me this is the my shell script. `#!/bin/sh
DIR=/users/Desktop/data
FILE=games.xml
cd $DIR

awk '/<game.*start="(Friday|Monday)">/{skip=1;} 1{if(!skip)print;} /<\/game>/{skip=0}' games.xml > newfile.xml && mv newfile.xml games.xml`

Comment: I have multiple nodes which start="Thursday" and start="Monday" Is that the reason this doesn't work?

Comment: @Jotne Do you have any suggestion for me? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean does not work? Do you get any error?

Comment: I'm sorry. It works but unfortunately my requirement changes. How can I achieve if game tag has multiple attributes like `<game date="2015-09-10 17:30 PDT" start="Friday" sporttype="soccer" sportids="125"> `

Comment: found the solution. Thanks for the tip. `awk '/<game.*start="(Thursday|Monday)"[^>]+>/{skip=1;} 1{if(!skip)print;} /<\/game>/{skip=0}' weeklySchedule.xml > newfile.xml `